# Merge xml in AS3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, merge, namespaces

I'd like to merge multiple xml file in AS3. All my xml file are on the same map :

```
<feed>
  <entry>
    <id>xxx</id>
    <link href="http://www.google.fr/"/>
    <title>xxx</title>
    <numShops>30</numShops>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

I want to do this :

```
<feed>
  <entry>
    <id>xxx</id>
    <link href="http://www.google.fr/"/>
    <title>xxx</title>
    <numShops>30</numShops>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>xxx</id>
    <link href="http://www.google.fr/"/>
    <title>xxx</title>
    <numShops>30</numShops>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>xxx</id>
    <link href="http://www.google.fr/"/>
    <title>xxx</title>
    <numShops>30</numShops>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

Have you any idea how to do this ? 
thx

Comment: May be this is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075526/as3-merging-xml-files

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
private function appendNodes(a: XML, b: XML) : void {
    for each(var node: XML in b.children()){
        a.appendChild(node);
    }
}
```

The first XML object would be 'a' and then you would call this function for each subsequent XML, passing them in the second param. All the entry nodes will be appended to the first XML object.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with appendChild.

```
mergeXML.appendChild(myXML);
```

And it works fine ! Thanks for your help